# Rendering a list in a razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this controller

```
// GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Users> Users = new List<Models.Users>()
            {
                new Users() {CustomerID = "12", Email = "Email1" },
                new Users() {CustomerID = "22", Email = "Email2" },
                new Users() {CustomerID = "13", Email = "Email3" },
                new Users() {CustomerID = "14", Email = "Email4" },
            };

            return View();
        }
```

And this view

```
@model IEnumerable<MB.eXum.Models.Users>   
<h2>Index</h2> 
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CustomerID)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerID)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

When I run the solution I get the error in the code line

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
```

An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.xeqljjsw.dll but was not handled in user code

What can I do to solve the error?

Comment: Right click inside `Index` method and add a view. Use options to create it as strongly typed one and you will get idea further.

Comment: Yes. But I get this error:An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.xeqljjsw.dll but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 1):

Change your return to include your list, like this:

```
return View(Users);
```

Currently, your model will be null.

Answer (score 1):

In your Razor view, you wait for a list of users, so you must pass that from controller to view.

In razor view you wait for the following list

```
@model IEnumerable<MB.eXum.Models.Users>
```

And in your controller you must pass a list of objects of this type to the view like this

```
  return View(Users);
```

where Users is the list that you created.

```
   List<Users> Users = new List<Models.Users>()
            {
                new Users() {CustomerID = "12", Email = "Email1" },
                new Users() {CustomerID = "22", Email = "Email2" },
                new Users() {CustomerID = "13", Email = "Email3" },
                new Users() {CustomerID = "14", Email = "Email4" },
            };
```

More about MVC here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/54576/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-View-Controller-Ar

Answer (score 1):

Your View is expecting a collection of `Users`.

Now in your controller, you are creating `Users` and are putting them inside a *List* but then when that is done, you are returning nothing instead of the Collection of Users you just created, hence the `NullReferenceException`.

> View - Creates a ViewResult object that renders a view to the response

Your `ViewResult` object is your *List* which you named `Users` so to get around that error you need to:

```
return View(Users);
```